# Framework7 - Global State in React Application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, html-framework-7

I need a central storage solution for my Data. In my example for the Shopping cart Items or User Credentials. 
But I want to use the Lifecycle of React. So when the Data changes my Application should render the DOM Tree again.

Framework 7 provides the "data" and "params" Properties, that I can access on every single page through the "this.$f7" Object. But there is not "setData" function to rerender the DOM when Data changes.

Comment: You could use [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to keep a shopping cart that all components can use.

Comment: Thank's that helps me a lot!

Comment: Great! You're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented the context of my App:

```
import UserContext from '../context/UserContext';

export default class extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      shoppingcartitems: [],
    }
  }

  render(props) {
    return (
      <UserContext.Provider value={{ 
            state: this.state, 
            setState: function(param){this.setState(param)}.bind(this)
        }}>
      <App params={f7params} onInit={this.onInit()}>
        ...
      </App>
      </UserContext.Provider>
      );
  }
}
```

Now I can Access it in every other File I need it:

```
import UserContext from '../../context/UserContext';

export default class CartPage extends React.Component {
    static contextType = UserContext;

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.context.state);

        this.context.setState({ hello: "World!"});
    }

}
```

Comment: Good Article to this Topic: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/reacts-new-context-api-how-to-toggle-between-local-and-global-state-c6ace81443d0